# Jquery Timer to run procedure every 5 minutes

Tags: jquery, html

I've got the following Jquery code that goes to a webservice via ajax to receive data to populate 2 gauges. It rus on pageload but I would like it to run and update the gauages every 5 minutes. How do I do this please?

My code is:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CarService.asmx/GetResponseTime",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var TicketResponse = response.d;
            var opts = {
                lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
                angle: 0.05, // The length of each line
                lineWidth: 0.44, // The line thickness
                pointer: {
                    length: 0.75, // The radius of the inner circle
                    strokeWidth: 0.035, // The rotation offset
                    color: '#374767' // Fill color
                },
                limitMax: 'false',   // If true, the pointer will not go past the end of the gauge
                colorStart: '#67c2ef',   // Colors
                colorStop: '#67c2ef',    // just experiment with them
                strokeColor: '#f2f4f8',   // to see which ones work best for you
                generateGradient: true
            };
            var target = document.getElementById('gauge1'); // your canvas element
            var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts); // create sexy gauge!
            gauge.maxValue = 200; // set max gauge value
            gauge.animationSpeed = 32; // set animation speed (32 is default value)
            gauge.set(100); // set actual value

            $.each(TicketResponse, function (index, car) {

                gauge.set(car.CurrentTime); // set actual value

                $('#lblAvgResponseTime').text(car.CurrentTime);
                $('#lblAvgResponseTimePercent').text(car.diffPercent + ' %');
                $("#iResponseTimeArrow").removeClass();

                if (car.diffPercent < 0) {
                    //Closure time going up ==== BAD
                    $("#iResponseTimeArrow").addClass("fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up text-danger");
                }
                else {
                    //Closure time going down ===== GODD
                    $("#iResponseTimeArrow").addClass("fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down text-success");
                }
            });

        },
        failure: function (msg) {
            $('#output').text(msg);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CarService.asmx/GetClosureTime",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var TicketClosure = response.d;

            var opts2 = {
                lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
                angle: 0.05, // The length of each line
                lineWidth: 0.44, // The line thickness
                pointer: {
                    length: 0.75, // The radius of the inner circle
                    strokeWidth: 0.035, // The rotation offset
                    color: '#374767' // Fill color
                },
                limitMax: 'false',   // If true, the pointer will not go past the end of the gauge
                colorStart: '#fabb3d',   // Colors
                colorStop: '#fabb3d',    // just experiment with them
                strokeColor: '#f2f4f8',   // to see which ones work best for you
                generateGradient: true
            };
            var target = document.getElementById('gauge2'); // your canvas element
            var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts2); // create sexy gauge!
            gauge.maxValue = 200; // set max gauge value
            gauge.animationSpeed = 32; // set animation speed (32 is default value)

            $.each(TicketClosure, function (index, car) {

                gauge.set(car.CurrentTime); // set actual value

                $('#lblAvgCloseTime').text(car.CurrentTime);
                $('#lblAvgCloseTimePercent').text(car.diffPercent + ' %');
                $("#iClosureTimeArrow").removeClass();

                if (car.diffPercent < 0)
                {
                    //Closure time going up ==== BAD
                    $("#iClosureTimeArrow").addClass("fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up text-danger");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Closure time going down ===== GODD
                    $("#iClosureTimeArrow").addClass("fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down text-success");
                }         
            });
        },

        failure: function (msg) {
            $('#output').text(msg);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: use setInterval(function(){ // your code },300000);

Comment: Wrap these `$.ajax` call in a function then in `document-ready` handler, call your function and use `setInterval(YourFunctionName,300000); ` to call after 5 second

Comment: This might be a daft question and I apologise as I'm quite new to Jquery but how to I wrap it up in a function please. I've managed to put the SetInterval code in and it works but obviously not on pageload so will need to put it in a function and then call the function on the pageload.

Comment: ah... I've done it.... Easy when you know how :-). Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript `setInterval()` function:

`setInterval(function() {
    updateGauges();
}, 30000);`

(30000 milliseconds = 5 minutes)

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp